# Swap image when hover with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a image in my `.img-area` div and my `img` tag has `data-list-1`and `data-list-2`attribute.When I hover on my `.img-area img` div my image must swap with attribute `data-list-1`and `data-list-2`with fade effect and when I hoverout it must swap with default img.

I get attribute and src but I couldn't change each image with fade efect

You can see my works on demo

```js
$(function(){
 
  $(".img-area img").hover(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var defaultImg = elem.attr("src");
    var data_1 = elem.attr("data-list-1");
    var data_2 = elem.attr("data-list-2");
    
    $(".show").html("Default image: "+defaultImg+"<br>Data 1 img:"+data_1 +"<br/>Data 2 img:"+ data_2);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.img-area{
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}
.img-area img{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="img-area">
  <img src="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logs-2-426x351.jpg" data-list-1="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/06.jpg" data-list-2="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.jpg">
</div>
  
  <div class="img-area">
  <img src="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logs-2-426x351.jpg" data-list-1="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/06.jpg" data-list-2="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.jpg">
</div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need two images, one over the other, than fadeout, in the upper

Comment: what do you mean ? I have one image and couldn't I change src of images with data-list-x attributes ?

Comment: Where is the `'.show'` element? Do you wish to fade the original image into displaying both `data` images, then back?

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rmtzg8z/1/) hope it helps

Comment: yes @rabelloo exactly as you say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with JQuery animate.

```js
$(function(){
 
  $(".img-area img").hover(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent(); 
    
    var defaultImg = elem.attr("src");
    var data_1 = elem.attr("data-list-1");
    var data_2 = elem.attr("data-list-2");
    
    parentDiv.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000, function(){ elem.attr("src",data_1)}).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000, function(){ elem.attr("src",data_2)}).animate({ opacity: 1 },3000);
  
    
    elem.animate({"src":data_1},"slow");
    

  });
  
});
```

```css
.img-area{
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}
.img-area img{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="img-area">
  <img src="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logs-2-426x351.jpg" data-list-1="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/06.jpg" data-list-2="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.jpg">
</div>
  
  <div class="img-area">
  <img src="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logs-2-426x351.jpg" data-list-1="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/06.jpg" data-list-2="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.jpg">
</div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited**

```js
var i =0;
var timer;


$(function(){
 
  $(".img-area img").on("mouseover",function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent(); 
    
    var defaultImg = elem.attr("src");
    var data_1 = elem.attr("data-list-1");
    var data_2 = elem.attr("data-list-2");
    
    var imageList = [data_1,data_2,data_1]
  
    myanimation(parentDiv,elem,imageList,defaultImg);
    

  });
  
});

var myanimation = function(parentElem,elem,imageList,defaultimage)
{
  if(i <imageList.length)
  {
     clearInterval(timer);
     parentElem.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000, function(){ elem.attr("src",imageList[i])}).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
    timer = setInterval(function(){ i++;
       myanimation(parentElem,elem,imageList,defaultimage) }, 6000);
  }
  else
  {
    clearInterval(timer);
    parentElem.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 3000, function(){ elem.attr("src",defaultimage)}).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 3000);
  }
  
  
  
}
```

```css
.img-area{
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
}
.img-area img{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="img-area">
  <img src="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logs-2-426x351.jpg" data-list-1="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/06.jpg" data-list-2="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.jpg">
</div>
  
  <div class="img-area">
  <img src="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/logs-2-426x351.jpg" data-list-1="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/06.jpg" data-list-2="http://themewich.com/struck/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/05.jpg">
</div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's a great example how about if I have `data-list-3` and `data-list-4` than what do I have to do ? I have `data-list-3` and `data-list-4`and this list can be empty or not it can be slide ?

Comment: and I guess there is a little bug..when I hoverout image must be default and slide must be finished

Comment: if you have more than 1 data attribute i will suggest you to put image src in an array and then call the function to animate one by one. The second is not a bug, the requirement itself is not implemented. You can do that easily on mouseout event.

Comment: so that how shall I replace my html and js?

Comment: I will be wait.

Comment: check the update, was a tough day in office so got a little late

Comment: image of `data-list-3` is not apper and slide is not work second hover but thanks your helping you are so good man

Comment: i have tried with 3 images and its working fine, hope you are adding it in the imageList. I purposely added .one binding  if you need it on every hover just change it to .on.

Comment: no I'm talking from example when you hoverout the image is not set default and if I hover second time than slide is not working :)

Comment: try now, i left it as an exercise for you but its ok, i have changed it now. it will work on each hover and will stop on the default image at last

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload=function(){
 imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    img=imgs[i];
    container=document.createElement("div");
    img.parentNode.appendChild(container);
    container.appendChild(img);
    img2=document.createElement("img");
    img2.src=img.getProperty("secondsrc");
    container.appendChild(img2);
    img2.id="secondimg";
    img.id="firstimage";
    container.style.width=img.width;
    container.style.height=img.height;
    }};
```

css:

```
#firstimage{
  z-index:3;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:1;
  transition: all ease 2s;
  }
  #firstimage:hover{
  opacity:0;
  }
```

html:

```
<img src="url" secondsrc="url2">
```